# If-statement not working Javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Okay, so here is my code.

```
.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: "data.php",
        data:{
            number:number, sprint_count:sprint_count
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){


            var count = data.length;
            var PlannedSprint = 0;

            for(var i = 0; i<count; i++){
                var Column = data[i].Column;
                if(PlannedSprint !== data[i].PlannedSprint){

                    $("#div"+Column+"_"+Team).append(data[i].PlannedSprint);

                 }  



                var PlannedSprint = data[i].PlannedSprint;
                var Team = data[i].Team;

                var Element = data[i].Element;


                $("#div"+Column+"_"+Team).append(Element);
            }
        }
    });
```

I want the IF-statement to work as long as the `data[i].PlannedSprint` isn't the same as `PlannedSprint`. But for some reason the IF-statement isn't working. Why is it so, what is wrong with the if-statement?

In my mind I think it should work like this:

```
var PlannedSprint = 0; // Set it to 0
if(PlannedSprint !== data[i].PlannedSprint){ // cause of PlannedSprint being set to 0 before this I believe it should work cause the data[i].PlannedSprint wont be 0.
var PlannedSprint = data[i].PlannedSprint; // And then this will give PlannedSprint a new value for the next loop instead of 0.
```

But this is not working, can someone explain!

Comment: Why don't you use != just

Comment: I don't know, i changed it to != but it didn't make any diffrence, still not working!

Comment: That means the problem is with data[i].PlannedSprint.Try to alert both values

Comment: What do you get if you log the values of `data[i].PlannedSprint`?

Answer (score 2):

You're redefining the variable inside the `if` statement. just remove the `var` inside.

```
var PlannedSprint = 0;
if(PlannedSprint !== data[i].PlannedSprint){
    PlannedSpint = data[i].PlannedSprint; // no "var"
```

I won't enter into a long description of why this occurs, you should read up on javascript "Hoisting" to understand this behaviour further.

Answer (score 0):

May you missing if statement closing tag (})
and var PlannedSprint declared 2 times

Comment: This should probably be a comment as you are simply seeking clarification from the asker.

Comment: Yes I know but I must have 50 reputation,,
however thnx for notify me :)

Comment: reputation :) repititions are something different.

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement is never true, because you always compare the previous with the next element.